# SharePoint 2013 site not accepting credentials

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, site, credentials

We have a SharePoint 2013 site created on one of our test servers. It is not prompting for credentials quite often. Even if we provide correct credentials it doesn't accept and prompts. The same AD server is being used by another test server and everything is working fine there. I have checked the regedit, IIS server manager, internet options settings. But it does not worked. Even SharePoint Timer Service is restarted and Cache is being cleared, disable loopback check was set but it was a temporary solution. We want a permanent fix for it. We have even restarted the server but it works fine for an hour or so and then prompts for credentials again. We would appreciate if you could provide a permanent fix for it.

Comment: have you checked this link : http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/04/sharepoint-keeps-asking-for-password.html

Comment: Thanks Anuja.. for your reply. I went through the mentioned site but the options specified there didn't work for me.

Comment: are you accessing the site from server or from the PC? did you added the site into trust zone? check if Kerberos is enabled on the web application

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a long time ago but i've found a workaround for this issue below:

Follow method 1 if you are on production.

Dev/testing however, feel free to follow method 2.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/896861

Just replying so if anyone else in the future comes across this issue they can find it :)